# PWA [sw-toolbox]: How to cache offline page with all resources?

Tags: caching, web-applications, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-toolbox

I have a page which i would like to use as offline fallback.

The problem is, that in this page i have a ~10 of js/css resources and ~20 images.
It's silly to point each one in `precache` array by hand.
Also, it's hard to maintain - all resource changes in html template will be affect `sw.js`.

Is there a option to precache `.html` page with all resources (js/css/png) ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You would most likely want to have your build scripts include the static assets in the precache array in your SW. Not by hand.

Comment: Can you send any example?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Google's method](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/prefetch/service-worker.js) for some time now and has never failed me.  SW toolbox didn't give me the results I wanted.